# Python 2.7 - crashing on subprocess.py

Tags: python-2.7

Python 2.7 - crashing on subprocess.py - Windows Error: [Error 2] The system cannot find file

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I have searched the rest of the questions and tried all the path settings and environmental variables and all that seems fine.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What command did you invoke? Or what python code caused the error?

Answer (score 0):

> "WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

I had the same error when I want to envoke a programm which isn't installed (I use ubuntu instead of windows).

http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#exceptions

try to excute the command manually in the shell , to get the real error

or use this fine method :

```
from subprocess import CalledProcessError, check_output

try:
    output = check_output(["ls", "non existent"])
except CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e.returncode)
```

N.B: in my system (ubuntu) , I get :

> ls: cannot access non existent: No such file or directory
>   2

In windows there is no "ls" command , you will get exception meaning that.

from :
[Check a command's return code when subprocess raises a CalledProcessError exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316398/check-a-commands-return-code-when-subprocess-raises-a-calledprocesserror-except)

check this :
[Using subprocess to run Python script on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912830/using-subprocess-to-run-python-script-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Use list while running command via subproccess.
list should be created by follows:
Suppose you want ot run command :

```
ls -l
```

Then command should be

```
cmd = ["ls" "-l" ]
subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```