# Continuing script after failure on os.system call python

Tags: python, os.system

I have a script I have written to scan a directory of text files and if it finds them, it creates a system call to run the script on the txt file. I am still working on a couple little bugs that causes some of my system calls to fail. I would like, however, for this NOT to kill my script. I would just like to be informed of the error then move on with my life. It seems any successful call returns 0 while any call that resulted in error returns n. I tried to compare the result with 0 but it never gets that far. Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this??

```
import sys, getopt, os

def main(argv):

    def scan_dir(path):
            temp_path = path
            print temp_path
            for file in os.listdir(path):
                    temp_path += file
                    if file.endswith(".txt"):
                            result = os.system("python callscript.py -i %s" % path)
                            if result != 0
                                    print "Error!"

                    temp_path = path


    def usage():
            print "usage:  dostuff.py [hi:]\n \
                  \t -h\t print usage\n \
                  \t -i\t directory path\n"
            sys.exit(2)

    if(len(argv) == 0):
            usage()

    path = ''

    try:
            opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:",["path="])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
            usage()

    for opt, arg in opts:
            if opt == '-h':
                    usage()

            elif opt in ("-i", "--ipath"):
                    path = arg
    if path.endswith('/') == False:
            path += '/'

    scan_dir(path)



if __name__ == "__main__":
main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: You can look into a try except for this

Comment: Why use `os` in the first place if your loop is in Python and the script is in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the subprocess module in particular [check_call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call), catching a `CalledProcessError`  which would be raised for any non-zero exit status:

```
 from subprocess import check_call,CalledProcessError      

  try:
       check_call(["python", "callscript.py", "-i",path])
  except CalledProcessError as e:
       print e.message
```

Not that easy to follow your code, I  would suggest not nesting all the other functions in main. I would also use [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) to find the txt files:

```
from glob import  glob

def scan_dir(path):
    files = (os.path.join(path,f) for f in glob(os.path.join(path,"*.txt")))
    for fle in files:    
        try:
            check_call(["python", "callscript.py", "-i", fle])
        except CalledProcessError as e:
            print e.message

def usage():
    print "usage:  dostuff.py [hi:]\n \
          \t -h\t print usage\n \
          \t -i\t directory path\n"
    sys.exit(2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    if not args:
        usage()
    path = ''
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(args, "hi:",["path="])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
            usage()

    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == '-h':
                usage()
        elif opt in ("-i", "--ipath"):
                    path = arg
    if not path.endswith('/'):
            path += '/'
    scan_dir(path)
```

Comment: @kennedyl, no prob, you should really always log the errors or at least print them out instead of just ignoring them, the answer below suggests using Popen which will not wait for a return code and using shell=True is not usually a good idea.

Comment: I got everything working. My apologies for the hard to read code earlier and thanks for your help. I tend to modularize my code once I have functionality. Below is my final product. I am curious, though, what the benefit of glob is over my implementation??

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I knew I had to do exception handling but didn't know what. Now I don't have to monitor my scripts and restart them.

Answer (score 0):

To catch errors and outputs without stopping your main process, I suggest using the subprocess module.

```
import subprocess

processToRun = "python callscript.py -i %s" % path
proc = subprocess.Popen (processToRun, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print(proc.returncode)
```

Comment: Not sure about the down vote here. check_call is only needed if you want an exception thrown. The main code running popen will keep going with its life even if the child process returns a non-zero code. See this other post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316398/check-a-commands-return-code-when-subprocess-raises-a-calledprocesserror-except

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are calling to invoke a python script, you should consider integrate that into your own python program.
2. Otherwise, you should use the subprocess module, this is recommended in the python documentation as shown in [os.system](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system). The documentation also suggests writing the replacement in this way [substitute for os.system](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements). Refer to section 17.1.4.3. for how to catch the exception.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution:

```
import sys, getopt, os    
from subprocess import check_call, CalledProcessError


def scan_dir(path):

    fail_count = 0
    success = []
    failure = []

    temp_path = path
    print temp_path
    for file in os.listdir(path):
            temp_path += file
            if file.endswith(".txt"):
                    try:
                            check_call(["python", "callscript.py","-i", temp_path])
                            success.append(file)
                    except CalledProcessError as e:
                            print e.message
                            failure.append(file)
                            fail_count += 1
                            continue
            temp_path = path

    if fail_count > 0:
            f = open("log.txt", "w")
            print ("%d Errors occurred during conversion. Check log.txt for details" % fail_count)
            f.write("The following files were successfully converted:\n")
            for s in success:
                    f.write("\t-%s\n" % s)

            f.write("\n\nThe following files failed to be converted:\n")
            for a in failure:
                    f.write("\t-%s\n" % a)
            f.close()
    else:
            print "All files converted successfully!"


def usage():
    print "usage:  dostuff.py [hi:]\n \
          \t -h\t print usage\n \
          \t -i\t directory path\n"
    sys.exit(2)

def main(argv):

    if(len(argv) == 0):
            usage()

    path = ''

    try:
            opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:",["path="])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
            usage()

    for opt, arg in opts:
            if opt == '-h':
                    usage()
elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
                    path = arg
    if path.endswith('/') == False:
            path += '/'

    scan_dir(path)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```